# Show text before div loads

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to display text before particular div loads but I have a problem where first .entry-content blinks / shows, and after that #loading shows up, .entry-content disappears, and after few seconds .entry-content shows up and #loading disappears.
So, the problem is .entry-content is displaying first, despite this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
// when user browses to page
$('.entry-content').hide();
$('#loading').show();

// then when the #content div has loaded
$(window).bind('load', function() {
$('#loading').hide();
$('.entry-content').fadeIn('slow');
})
});
</script>

<div id="loading">
<!-- this is just moment place -->
<div style="text-align: center">
<h2>Just Moment...</h2>
</div>
</div>

<div class="entry-content">
<!-- this is entry content -->
Whats up mate?
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put a display none on the entry-content, to avoid the blink.  Either inline, or with a CSS rule.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```html
<script>
  jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('.entry-content').fadeIn('slow');
  });
</script>

<div id="loading">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <h2>Just Moment...</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="entry-content">
  Whats up mate?
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.entry-content {
  display: none;
}
```